# Tower of Hanoi C++(using recursion)

Tags: c++, recursion, stack, towers-of-hanoi

I wrote the following code as a practice exercise.
I'm getting incorrect output when I print the destination stack.
Can anyone please point out where I'm going wrong ?

```
//Tower of Hanoi using Stacks!
#include<iostream.h>
#include<conio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

class Stack
{
private:
    int *t;
    int length, top;

public:
    Stack(int len)
    {
        length=len;
        t= new int[len];
        top=-1;
    }

    ~Stack()
    {
        delete []t;
    }

    void push(int d)
    {
        top++;
        t[top]=d;
    }

    int pop()
    {
        top--;
        return t[top+1];
    }

    void printstack()
    {
        int cur=top;
        while(cur>-1)
        {
            cout<<t[cur]<<endl;
            cur--;
        }
    }
};

void MoveTowerofHanoi(int disk, Stack *source, Stack *temp, Stack *destination)
{
    if (disk==0)
    {
        destination->push(source->pop());
    }
    else
    {
        MoveTowerofHanoi(disk-1,source,temp,destination);
        destination->push(source->pop());
        MoveTowerofHanoi(disk-1,temp,destination,source);
    }
}

void main()
{
    clrscr();
    int disks;
    cout<<"Enter the number of disks!"<<endl;
    cin>>disks;
    Stack* source=new Stack(disks);
    for(int i=0; i<disks; i++) {
        source->push(disks-i);
    }
    cout<<"Printing Source!"<<endl;
    source->printstack();
    Stack* temp=new Stack(disks);
    Stack* destination=new Stack(disks);
    MoveTowerofHanoi(disks,source,temp,destination);
    cout<<"Printing Destination!"<<endl;
    destination->printstack();
    getch();
}
```

Here's the output I'm getting:

```
Enter the no. of disks!  
3  
Printing Source!  
1  
2  
3  
Printing Destination!  
-4
```

---

After editing, the code looks like this:

```
    void MoveTowerofHanoi(int disk, Stack *source, Stack *destination, Stack *temp)
{
    if (disk==1)
    {
        destination->push(source->pop());
    }
    else
    {
        MoveTowerofHanoi(disk-1,source,temp,destination);
        destination->push(source->pop());
        MoveTowerofHanoi(disk-1,temp,destination,source);
    }
}
```

the first mistake was:

```
void MoveTowerofHanoi(int disk, Stack *source, Stack *temp, Stack *destination)
```

the second was:

```
if (disk==0)
```

Many thanks to all for helping!

---

Changes made to stack class:

```
void push(int d)
{
     if(top<length-1)
    {
    top++;
    t[top]=d;
    }

}

int pop()
{
    if(top>-1)
    {
    top--;
    return t[top+1];
    }
}
```

Comment: You definitely don't need any pointers in `main`, which must return `int`, not `void`, and if the point is the Towers of Hanoi, why can't you just use `std::stack`? Also, `iostream.h` is not, and has never been, a standard header.

Comment: You're missing a semicolon after the class definition, that shouldn't even compile. And you indentation is, well, you have no indentation, which makes the code very hard to read.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg fixed the indentation, but i did not add the semicolon

Comment: Get a modern C++ book, yours is bad. The code contains numerous errors and will be rejected by modern compilers as invalid.

Comment: @nijansen I was wrong about the semicolon, I missread the code.

Comment: Try running in a debugger, and step through the recursive calls line by line to see what happens.

Comment: And God where is the `delete` for the Stack objects?

Comment: @KonradRudolph Suggest some book please!

Comment: @chris my compiler doesn't take <iostream> as a valid header somehow it does take <iostream.h>
and how would main returning int make a difference ?

Comment: @IshaanSharma http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list See here for book recommendations

Comment: Are you using some pre-C++98 compiler?

Comment: @IshaanSharma, I really, *really*, **really** suggest getting a newer compiler. And `main` is required by the standard to return an `int`. If it doesn't, it's not valid C++.

Comment: @chris Is DevC++ fine?
also can you please elaborate on the mistakes i've made so that I can improve the program (and my skills :P).

Comment: I found this webpage [link](http://www.cs.cmu.edu/~cburch/survey/recurse/hanoiimpl.html)
It explains the algorithm which i have tried to follow closely.
Any help appreciated.

Comment: @IshaanSharma, Dev-C++ is an IDE. If you're going that route, use the newer one that got started on again and make sure the GCC compiler is the newest for best results. Anyway, just allocate variables normally instead of with pointers and `new`, use `int main`, and replace your `Stack` class usage with [`std::stack`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/stack), which has been tested extensively.

Comment: @IshaanSharma DevC++ is not a compiler but an IDE. DevC++ is using the gcc/g++ compiler and that is a really good one. Just be sure that you are using a recent version.

Comment: Work through the case with *one* disk by hand. I suggest you use pencil and paper and draw the towers as you trace the code. You should find the problem fairly quickly.

Comment: @molbdnilo I have edited the code and now it works!
please have a look at the new `towerofhanoi` funtion

Comment: @IshaanSharma, Have you changed the Stack class?

Comment: @cpp Yes! I have changed `push()` and `pop()` . I am updating changes in the post! Also please tell me if something is wrong with the destructor

Comment: @cpp can you tell me about memory leaks in my main ?

Answer (score 1):

This works:

```
//Tower of Hanoi using Stacks!
#include<iostream>
//#include<conio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<vector>
#include<algorithm>
using namespace std;

void print_elem(int elem)
{
    cout << elem << endl;       
}

class Stack{
public:
    void push(int d){t.push_back(d);}
    int pop()
    {
        int d=t.back();
        t.pop_back();
        return d;
    }
    void printstack()
    {
        for_each(t.rbegin(),t.rend(),print_elem);
    }
private:
    vector<int> t;

};

void MoveTowerofHanoi(int disk, Stack *source, Stack *temp, Stack *destination)
{
    if (disk==1)
    {
        destination->push(source->pop());
    }
    else
    {
        MoveTowerofHanoi(disk-1,source,destination,temp);
        destination->push(source->pop());
        MoveTowerofHanoi(disk-1,temp,source,destination);
    }
}

int main()
{
    int disks;
    cout<<"Enter the number of disks!"<<endl;
    cin>>disks;
    Stack* source = new Stack();
    for(int i=disks; i>0; --i) {
        source->push(i);
    }

    cout<<"Printing Source!"<<endl;
    source->printstack();
    Stack* temp = new Stack();
    Stack* destination = new Stack();
    MoveTowerofHanoi(disks,source,temp,destination);
    cout<<"Printing Destination!"<<endl;
    destination->printstack();
    delete source;
    delete temp;
    delete destination;
}
```

Comment: Note that for the Tower of Hanoi, you can never put a bigger disk on top of a smaller one on any of the stacks.  The stack class for ToH can, therefore, enforce this constraint, providing a more rigorous test for the algorithm. The stack class can also ensure that only the values 1..length are placed on the stack — again, a constraint specific to the ToH problem.  Of course, when the algorithm is correct, the extra checking doesn't help much, but when it is broken, it can be very helpful.